# When do Pro Tempore Moderators change?

Tags: support, pro-tem-moderators

How long is the term for a pro tempore moderator?

Nothing on the [Moderators FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role) or [Elections FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135360/theres-an-election-going-on-whats-happening-and-how-does-it-work?rq=1) mention what the term length is for moderators.

Comment: All moderators are considered to be in the role indefinitely. The pro tem moderators are appointed until the first election after which the elected moderators take the place of the pro tem mods. Pro tem mods are not exempt from running in an election.

Comment: *Tim Post*ed several case [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/259373/260388).

Answer (score 7):

The term is "until the graduation election".

Pro-tem mods are added when needs exceed current capacity.  This can be a straight-up addition, when the workload grows beyond what the original three moderators can handle; this happened on IPS, Genealogy & Family, Worldbuilding, and Christianity, to name a few.  Or it can be because an existing pro-tem stepped down, which is how I got two of my pro-tem diamonds (Writing and Beer, Wine, & Spirits).

If you feel your site needs more moderators, bring it up on your site -- though usually your existing moderators would lead the charge there.  If you feel your site needs *different* moderators -- that is, if you are unhappy with one or more of your current pro-tem mods -- then you need to raise the matter with SE, who appoints pro-tems.  Use the "contact us" link at the bottom of every page.  Removal of moderators is very, very rare, done only in the case of severe problems.  If you just don't like someone, you are unlikely to be successful.

While [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151606/162102) is mostly about removing *elected* moderators, you might find it helpful for understanding general philosophy and policy.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is when the existing pro-tem moderators cannot handle the workload, which might happen on sites about <s>controversial subjects</s> subjects where people have a lot of controversial opinions about. In that case, new forces can be called in; this recently happened on [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com). You can compare the difference between the [current moderator team](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1363/321) and the [original three](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/1363/1).

Comment: We requested and got a fourth pro tem moderator added to our team at [genealogy.se] when we saw an exceptional candidate and thought the additional moderator would help drive our site stats towards graduation.

Comment: They added more mods on IPS largely because the first three asked for them. There really wasn't a shift in moderation style. IPS grew quickly and regularly hits HNQ. HNQ generates the majority of the moderation tasks...

Comment: What is IPS and HNQ.

Comment: IPS = [interpersonal.se]; HNQ = Hot Network Questions

Answer (score 1):

They don't change until the beta graduates and a proper election is held. In the Parenting SE there was an election for Pro Tem moderators but only because one of the previously existing ones resigned.

Comment: The parenting election was a special case and may or may not be continued on other sites.