# If a pro-tem moderator was elected (not appointed), do they then face another election when a beta site graduates?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election, beta-sites

Many pro-tem moderators on older beta sites appear to have been appointed. However, for newer beta sites and in some cases of long running beta sites, they are now actually elected in.

The question is, when one of these long running beta sites then graduates, even though the appointed pro-tem moderators *will* definitely face election, will, or should, the previously elected pro-tem moderators *also* face (re-)election?

I've browsed a few links, mostly hanging off this question, [When do Pro Tempore Moderators change?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/312300/280335), but this (apparent) edge case doesn't appear to be documented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> when one of these long running beta sites then graduates ... will, or should, the previously elected pro-tem moderator also face (re-)election?

They will, according to [then staff member Jon Ericson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections#comment1030478_314459)

> On graduation, all moderators must stand for re-election if they wish to continue in the role. There will be no difference between moderators who ran for an election during beta and moderators we appoint.

Should they? Perhaps not; if the pro-tempore election was competitive and recent, results for a graduation election shouldn't be much different than they were the last time.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It's the last line... *should they?*. IMHO, it just feels a wee-bit pointless (maybe) to have to re-run. I guess I *can* see possible reasons both for and against having to re-run, though.

Comment: Many of them wete elected early in the Beta and should be re-elected if they are to be apppinted permanently.