# Is the Community Moderator position permanent?

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderators

I would assume that once elected Community Moderator, that position can be indefinitely retained when carrying out the moderator duties.

However, if a moderator can no longer carry out his or her duties (due to time constraints, etc.) is there a procedure in place for resigning or removing a Community Moderator?  Or would the person retain their position anyway.

There isn't really concern on my part, just curiosity.

I have noted the [Should Community Moderators be “elected for life”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/984/should-community-moderators-be-elected-for-life-or-have-terms?rq=1) post, but that seems to be suggesting an actual term limit.

Comment: With regards to removing a moderator, yes, there is a procedure for that: [Handling calls to remove a moderator](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151606/handling-calls-to-remove-a-moderator)

Comment: @Bart very interesting thank you

Comment: The resignation process is sending an email to Stack Exchange with "I CAN'T TAKE THIS ANYMOREEEEEEE" in the subject line.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The term is effectively for as long as you want to be a moderator.  You can resign if you like.  There's also a provision to remove moderators who are active on their site for several months without participating in moderator activity.

Comment: They do remove mods who disappear for a long period of time and who can not be reached.

Comment: @Catija Can the mod request to be reinstated if they had a valid reason?

Comment: @DogLover At the very least, its likely to be on a case by case basis. For the moment, there's no official, public guidence as far as I know on this.